# Persist data on refresh after passing it via shared service

Tags: angular

I passed some data from component A (on a click event) to B using the following shared service.

```
@Injectable()
export class HostelService{
    private book = new BehaviorSubject<String>("");

    currentBook = this.book.asObservable();

    getBookDetails(book){
        this.book.next(book);
    }
}
```

However, as expected, on page refresh the data passed on component B gets lost. My question is, how do I get it to persist until the next click event from component A. Thanks.

Edit: Tried localStorage

In component B's `ngOnInit()` I tried the following:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.bookService.currentbook.subscribe(book => {
      this.book = book;
      localStorage.setItem("book", JSON.stringify(this.book));
      this.book = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("book"));
    });
```

Still doesn't persist.

Edit 2:

Okay, so I completely got rid of the service and stored the object in Component A directly in local storage (Inside the onclick) and simply used `getItem` in Component B. It seems to be working fine now. But what's the point of even using a shared service then? I guess it's not necessary in this case?

Comment: use local storage to save data.

Comment: You would have to store it *outside* the app (local/session storage), and retrieve it when the app restarts.

Comment: I've updated the original post with what I did. There's still an issue.

Comment: Shouldn't you save/read/test with local storage inside your subscribe handler?

Comment: Also move the `getItem` line inside the handler (and the `console.log` statement). The reason: the `let item = ...` line is executed before the handler.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Please check the update I've made.

Comment: There is no http-request involved here?